# Namespaces in autoloader

Tags: php, namespaces, autoloader

I'm making a Api and in the autoloader I want to use dynamic namespaces.

I want to make this because I'm want to use namespaces instead of using dynamic includes, this is better for later use.

Now I have this:

```
use Api\Modules\$controller;
use Api\Modules\$router;
```

but it doesn't work.

How can i make this dynamically or can't I do that?

Comment: Could you add _why_ you would want this? Perhaps your approach on the problem is not the correct one.

Comment: I want to make this because for later it will make it easier to call classes in other classes. So i thought why not make use of it in the base of the Api, the autoloader.

Comment: Have you considered generating an autoloader with [composer](http://getcomposer.org)?